# What value PTC Thermistor should I choose for over-current protection for a child's electronics kit?

Tags: current-limiting, thermistor, component-values

What is an appropriate value for a PTC thermistor used in a 3-cell AA battery pack to provide over-current protection if the terminalsare shorted? Current draw during normal operation will be only a few hundred milliamps)

I'm looking to make something similar to this: [SnapCircuits 3 battery holder](http://www.snapcircuits.net/products/product_details/battery_holder_4.5v_(3_x_aa)=NzMz) so my son can experiment with connecting switches, leds, motors, etc. together without a risk of melting something.

Comment: How will he learn if he can't melt things by accident? :P

Comment: He's been there, done that, and I've already thrown out the melted battery holder, @marcelm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like a 0.5A leaded PTC. For example, a Littelfuse [RXEF050](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=SCD25219&DocType=SS&DocLang=EN), which is a radial leaded type. It has a resistance of less than 1\$\Omega\$ when 'on' and a hold current of only 50mA. It  will conduct at least 0.5A indefinitely without opening, and will trip in about four seconds at 2.5A (at  reasonable temperatures).

With PTC resettable fuses (and fuses in general) there are a couple of  other things to consider- maximum voltage  (when open) and maximum current that the fuse can interrupt. Some battery technologies can supply enormous current, but I'll assume you have alkaline cells which can produce less than 10A. Checking the ratings on the RXEF050, we have:

[image]

So it can interrupt a fault current of up to 40A at 72V, which should be more than safe for a few AA Alkaline batteries (perhaps not for NiCd types though).

If he leaves the short in place it will drain the battery relatively slowly if it trips, however if the batteries are getting weak and cannot produce enough current to trip the fuse, they will be drained much, much faster.

Comment: Power will be 3xAA (probably NiMH). Depending on the exact cells they could deliver 50A+ so il be sure to look at the max interrupt current. Looks like also need to verify the current draw of my other various baubles to be sure thry won't trip whatever part I end up choosing.

Comment: You're probably still okay with 40A interrupting capacity as the PTC itself has a fair bit of internal resistance (0.5 ohm minimum) and you won't get 50A with even an ideal source of only 3V- more like 5 or 6A. Checking the devices' draw is a very good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a PTC "thermistor" you should use a PTC Resettable fuse. Perhaps that is what you intended? Similar to a glass fuse, a resettable fuse will trip at a specified current and go high resistance to limit the current. It will remain high resistance until the current is removed. Then, after a short time to cool down, it will self-reset and can be used again.

Have a look at these: [Bourns](http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/mfr.pdf?sfvrsn=20)

If the highest current from your battery pack in normal operation is 300mA then you need to use a MF-R030. This has a Ihold current of 300mA, so it is specified not to trip with 300mA going through it at an ambient temperature of 23 degree C. It's Itrip value is 600mA, so it will definitely trip with 600mA going through it, although it will take a nearly 2 minutes to do so. With a current of 1.5A, such as a short circuit, it should trip in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft3Eqe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Current limiter and short-circuit indicator.*

Something similar to Figure 1 might work and could be installed in the battery holder.

R2 limits the current to 450 mA in the case of a short circuit. As the voltage drop across R2 increases towards 1.5 V D1 should begin to glow and will be very bright at about 10 mA on a short circuit. The downside of this scheme is that even at 100 mA a volt will be lost across R2.

Maximum power in R2 under short-circuit conditions will be \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} = \frac {4.5^2}{10} = 2~W \$ so choose a suitably big resistor and protect it from little fingers (while allowing ventilation).

If you can find a suitable PTC thermistor you could use it in place of R2 and still have the indication.